# Screen brightness of Dell inspiron N4050 is not changing

Tags: ati, windows-7, resolution, screen

I have installed all the drivers of my laptop (Dell inspiron N4050 with windows 7 professional) and now i am trying to minimize the brightness because its too much bright light is itching me.

1. Neither Fn+f4 key minimizes the brightness nor there is any option of adjustment in Control Panel/Hardware and Sound/Power Options.
2. Secondly video song become blurry when I switch to full screen and works well without full screen.

Please help me to sort this problem--thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get working brightness key. try following

press Alt+f2 , execute `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change this line

`GRUB_CMLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to something like below

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

**Open a terminal by Alt+ctrl +T, Execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot** . See if brightness keys are working.

Let us know the result. And for second question it is preferable to open a new question. As the title something different

Comment: Web-E i am using windows 7 as i have mentioned in my question please guide me for windows 7..

Comment: This isn't Q&A site for windows. This is for ubuntu only.